# add contents inside root tag of xml file

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have one existing xml file and want to add some contents to it.

Existing xml file:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:Reference Uri="/redfish/v1/Schemas/Resource_v1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource"/>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_0_0"/>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_0_2"/>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_4_0"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Service">
            <EntityContainer Name="Service" Extends="ServiceRoot.v1_0_0.ServiceContainer"/>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Now I want to add the following contents without modifying contents of existing file

My question is how to add contents of xml to existing file without modifying the contents of existing xml file inside this tag :  `<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">`

I tried with this piece of code:

```
new="""<edmx:Reference Uri="/redfish/v1/Schemas/Chassis_v1.xml">
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis"/>
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis.v1_0_0"/>
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis.v1_0_1"/>
</edmx:Reference>"""


tree = ET.parse('metadata.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

ET.register_namespace('edmx','http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx')
ET.register_namespace('','http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm')
root.text = new

print ET.tostring(root,method="html")
```

But output is:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">&lt;edmx:Reference Uri="/redfish/v1/Schemas/Chassis_v1.xml"&gt;
&lt;edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis"/&gt;
&lt;edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis.v1_0_0"/&gt;
&lt;edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis.v1_0_1"/&gt;
&lt;/edmx:Reference&gt;<edmx:Reference Uri="/redfish/v1/Schemas/Resource_v1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource"></edmx:Include>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_0_0"></edmx:Include>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_0_2"></edmx:Include>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_4_0"></edmx:Include>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema Namespace="Service">
            <EntityContainer Extends="ServiceRoot.v1_0_0.ServiceContainer" Name="Service"></EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Is the below answer is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to add your content in parent/root attribute, this code will add your content:

New content:

```
new="""<edmx:Reference Uri="/redfish/v1/Schemas/Chassis_v1.xml">
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis"/>
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis.v1_0_0"/>
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis.v1_0_1"/>
</edmx:Reference>"""
```

---

Code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse, Element
xml_doc = parse('metadata.xml') #parse xml file here
root = xml_doc.getroot()  #get root element here...
root.append(Element(new)) #new element/attribute you want to get 
xml_doc.write('metadata.xml', xml_declaration=True)
```

---

Output metadata.xml will be as follows:

```
<ns0:Edmx xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Version="4.0">
    <ns0:Reference Uri="/redfish/v1/Schemas/Resource_v1.xml">
        <ns0:Include Namespace="Resource" />
        <ns0:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_0_0" />
        <ns0:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_0_2" />
        <ns0:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_4_0" />
    </ns0:Reference>
    <ns0:DataServices>
        <ns1:Schema Namespace="Service">
            <ns1:EntityContainer Extends="ServiceRoot.v1_0_0.ServiceContainer" Name="Service" />
        </ns1:Schema>
    </ns0:DataServices>
    <!-- added new content here -->
<<edmx:Reference Uri="/redfish/v1/Schemas/Chassis_v1.xml">
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis"/>
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis.v1_0_0"/>
<edmx:Include Namespace="Chassis.v1_0_1"/>
</edmx:Reference> /></ns0:Edmx>
```